# Bind JSON TO availableTags in tag-it

Tags: json, tag-it

SEE http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/
http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/prototype.js

I tried it with setting

```
availableTags: [{ label: "JAVA(10)", value: 10 },
                        {label: "JAVA SCRIPT(11)", value: 11 }
                       ],
```

My idea is to get all language ids(in the auto complete) on a button click or some event on the DOM elements
How to achive this?

What should be structure of the JSON we use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The json structure you have created is sufficient.

```
var availableTags = [
   {value: 1, label: 'tag1'},
   {value: 2, label: 'tag2'},
   {value: 3, label: 'tag3'}
];

$("#myTags").tagit({
tagSource:availableTags});
```

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7KhDy/) gives the 'value' specified in the JSON rather than the label.